# Why gradle jars are written in `build/libs`?

Tags: gradle

According to the [documentation of the Jar plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html), the output directory is controlled by the `destinationDir` property:

> - **File** `destinationDir`
>
>   The directory where the archive is generated into.
>
>   Default with java plugin: `project.distsDir`

Looking at the [documentation of the Project class](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html) the same property is mentioned:

> **Properties added by the `java` plugin**
>
> - `distsDir`: The directory to generate TAR and ZIP archives into.
> - `distsDirName`: The name for the distributions directory. This in interpreted relative to the project' build directory.

And Googling a bit I find [a document specifying their defaults](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.BasePluginConvention.html#org.gradle.api.plugins.BasePluginConvention:distsDirName):

> - **File** `distsDir` (read-only)
>
>   The directory to generate TAR and ZIP archives into.
>
>   Default with java plugin: `${project.buildDir}/${project.distsDirName}`
> - **String** `distsDirName`
>
>   The name for the distributions directory. This in interpreted relative
>     to the project' build directory.
>
>   Default with java plugin: `'distributions'`

All these documents point to the same Gradle version, that matches the one I have installed.

I add this in my `build.gradle` to check the real values of these properties:

```
println("distsDirName = " + project.distsDirName)
println("distsDir = " + project.distsDir.toString())

jar {
    println("jar.destinationDir = " + destinationDir)
}
```

And finally, I run `./gradlew` and check the output:

```
distsDirName = distributions
distsDir = /home/ntrrgc/myProject/build/distributions
jar.destinationDir = /home/ntrrgc/myProject/build/libs
```

Why does `jar.destinationDir` not respect its documented default?

Comment: Searching in their source code I found [their unit tests actually expect this behavior](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/v3.2.1/subprojects/plugins/src/test/groovy/org/gradle/api/plugins/BasePluginTest.groovy#L151). Also, according to [BasePluginConvention](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.BasePluginConvention.html#org.gradle.api.plugins.BasePluginConvention:libsDir) docs, `libsDir` is *The directory to generate JAR and WAR archives into* while `distsDir` is for TAR and ZIP files. The only contradicting piece is the documentation of the Jar plugin.

Comment: Because a Gradle distribution is not a JAR. Usually this is a ZIP or TAR package with any files inside. It can be bunch of JARs or any other. For example, see `application` and `distribution` plugins docs. If you want to override `build/libs` use `libsDir` and `libsDirName`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think, @Alicia is right in pointing out that currently the [documentation of the Gradle Jar plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:destinationDir) is providing wrong information in the default value for the File destinationDir:

> File destinationDir
>
> The directory where the archive is generated into.
>
> Default with java plugin:
>
> project.distsDir

where default of distsDir is 'build/distributions' as can be [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:jar).

In my opinion, it should be

> File destinationDir
>
> The directory where the archive is generated into.
>
> Default with java plugin:
>
> project.libsDir

where default of libsDir is 'build/libs' as can be seen [here again](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:jar).

I have opened [Gradle issue #1086](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1086) for this. Let us see, what they answer.

Comment: They confirmed it, so I'm marking this as the correct answer :)